# Imacros - Looping multiple macros specific number of times using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, macros, nested

I play multiple Macros one after another, multiple times using a simply loop in javascript .js file as below

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
iimSet("loop", i);
iimPlay("1.iim");
iimPlay("2.iim");
iimPlay("3.iim");
}
```

but within the loop, i want each macro to be played specific number of times.

Say 1.iim  4 times, 2.iim 4 times and 3.iim full 10 times
How can i do that?
I tried adding "if" statement within the "for" loop for each macro

```
Var i1;
if(i1 <=4)
{iimPlay("1.iim");
 i1++;}
```

But that didn't work :(
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the "If" this way:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  iimSet("loop", i); //this will be run 10 times
  if(i<=4) {
    iimPlay("1.iim");//this will be run during the 4 first loops
  }
  if(i>4 && i<=8) {
    iimPlay("2.iim");//this will be run during the 4 next loops
  }
  iimPlay("3.iim"); //this will also be run 10 times
}
```

Comment: but i need to run every iim different number of times (as detailed in question)... not just 1 if will do?  Can you kindly edit the answer for that. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure I really understand what you mean. I edited the answer with what I believe will do, could you please give more details if this doesn't meets your needs ?

Comment: thanks but i needed 1st top run 4 times, 2nd to run 4 times too one after another and 3rd to run 10 times too. with your solution it runs 1st till 4 and then 2nd . Anyway i got help from you and understood and worked around it by removing the >4 & <=8 thing . Can you help with Regex ?...just posted a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152409/imacros-how-to-do-this-with-regex-supported-in-search-function Thanks