# IMACROS how to do this with Regex supported in search function

Tags: regex, search, replace, imacros

I am using IMACRO Firefox inbuilt editor to edit macros . I see it has an "REGULAR expressions" option while doing a search/replace function. See pic!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmWWu.jpg

As per their site..it supports DOTNET REGEX http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

How can i search for a line break using search function?

For. e.g.  i need to replace multiple such instances in macro like following

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:AB
```

with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:AB
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:SOLUTION
```

Note at that i have to replace 1 line with 2 lines so needs a line break

Can i enter some regex code in replace field to enter a break and then replace with 2 lines. Currently without that replaced text  (i.e 2 lines) comes as one line
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t waste your time with the built-in editor. Use more advanced ones: ‘Sublime Text’, ‘Notepad++’ etc. (The symbol of a line break (new line) is \n there.)

Comment: hmm.. ok started using Editplus